# Prog error: for replacing spaces with "%20"

Tags: c++

below is the prog i am compiling for replacing spaces with "%20" but when I run it output window shows blank and a message "arrays5.exe has occurred a prob"

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

void method(char str[], int len)               //replaces spaces with "%20"
{

    int spaces, newlen,i;

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
        if(str[i]==' ') spaces++;
    newlen=len+spaces*2;
    str[newlen]=0;
    for (i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            str[newlen-1]='0';
            str[newlen-2]='2';
            str[newlen-3]='%';
            newlen=newlen-3;
        }
        else
        {
            str[newlen-1]=str[i];
            newlen=newlen-1;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char str[20]="sa h ";
    method(str,5);
    cout <<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me finding the error.Thanks

Comment: Either, you're using C, or you're using C++. Please pick one. Having picked one, we will then need to point out why your algorithm is wrong and how it should be fixed, the correct approach depends on the language you pick...

Comment: Seeing as how you use `cout` and stuff, why not use `std::string`? It has a `replace` member function.

Comment: @acidzombie24: That's not a helpful comment, I suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spaces` is uninitialised before you increment it.

You should give it an initial, default value.

An uninitialised variable will have a value which is undefined by the specification. This value could be 0, if you're lucky but it is highly likely that this value will be anything in the range of values which the datatype may represent.

Your program will compile and run fine when `spaces` is initialised properly.

Comment: I also suggest that the length of the memory allocation should be passed in, if you keep this code... Otherwise you're still liable to have a buffer overrun.

Comment: For clarification, when you say the memory allocation, are you referring to the length of the `str` array?

Comment: Yes, that's memory allocated on the stack.

Comment: @Loggi..yes you were right the only prob was uninitialized var "spaces". Sometimes the prob is simple but still you dont figure out. thanks alot!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Help others by accepting this as the answer by checking the tick on the left, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fixing your problem, but providing a better solution. If you're using C++, then **you should** use the STL. You've got lots of classes and methods that do all of the job for you.

You could rewrite your 25 lines long method into this 4 lines long method(example included):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::string method(std::string str)
{
    size_t index;
    while((index = str.find(' ')) != std::string::npos)
        str = str.replace(index, 1, "%20");
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    std::string str("sa h ");
    str = method(str);
    cout <<str<<endl; // outputs sa%20h%20
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use std::string, and use the .replace method.  The reason your code doesn't work is because you're *overwriting* the input string in an odd way so I don't know if your expected output would be correct, however, the actual error you have is that you're potentially rewriting at index locations -3, -2, and -1. Consider the case where your first space is at index zero.

In C++, it's usually better to avoid char* unless you have a clear reason for doing so.  As a matter of good style (this is somewhat subjective), I would suggest that you do NOT modify your input arguments directly, but instead return the result.

Ie, your method prototype should be:

```
std::string method(std::string str)
```

There is no-longer a need to pass the length of the string, because std::string takes care of that.

Comment: If his string is `" "`, then newlen will equal 3 and he won't have an issue.

Comment: @sharth: I missed that (Damn I need coffee), but he'll still overwrite the end of the string.